# Case not working in Exists in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I have a scenario where i have to check a variable for it's default value, and if it has i have to check EXISTS part conditionally with Table2 and if it does not have the default value, i have to check EXISTS part conditionally with Table3.

Below is a sample code:-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CASE WHEN @boolVar = 0 THEN (SELECT 'X' FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1) ELSE (SELECT 'X' FROM tbl3 where tbl1.col1 = tbl3.col1) END)
```

Demo query with constants for testing purpose: -

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1=0) 
    ELSE (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1 = 2) END)
```

Note: - The above query always returning 1, even not a single condition is satisfying.

I know we can use OR operator for the same and any how we can achieve it, but i really want to know that in case both the tables have no rows satisfying their particular where clause, even it's returning all the rows from Table1.

I tried to explain the same with the demo query with constant values.

Please help.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1=0) ELSE (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1 = 2) END` returns a row. `EXISTS` checks for that. it doesn't matter that it returns a single column that happens to be `NULL`

Comment: your demo query will alwys returns NULL in sub query becos it does not match any of the where conditions

Comment: I am not sure query you have provided will return 1 as none of the conditions are matching

Comment: Ya @MartinSmith , i agree with you and tested but i could not understand that why it's retrning a row having NULL.

Comment: Ya @AnandPhadke, i agree with you and tested the same also, but i still could not understand that why it's retrning a row having NULL even none of the above individually haves a single row.

Comment: then what you expect it to return? If nothing is there it will use NULL as value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your query doesn't find any matching records, it will basically do:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL)
```

As a row containing a null value is still a row, the `EXISTS` command returns true.

You can add a condition to filter out the null row:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN @boolVar = 0 THEN (SELECT 'X' FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1)
      ELSE (SELECT 'X' FROM tbl3 where tbl1.col1 = tbl3.col1)
      END AS Y
  ) Z
  WHERE Y IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: hi @Guffa, thanks for the suggestion, but i still could not understand that why it's retrning a row having NULL even none of the above parts of the query individually returns a single row.

Comment: @GKRanjan - `SELECT CASE ...` without a where clause will always return a single row with the result of the expression.

Comment: @GKRanjan: It's because you are selecting one row containing the value from the `case` expression, so there will always be one row whatever the `case` returns. The `exists` function only checks if there are any rows or not, and doesn't care what the rows contain.

Comment: Hi, Guffa , Columns Y is not accessible in the same query so i have to check for IS NULL in upper query as below: - SELECT 1  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM(SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1=0) 
 ELSE (SELECT 'X' WHERE 1 = 2) END AS Y)T WHERE Y IS NOT NULL)  And it's working. Thanks.

Comment: @GKRanjan: Right...  you can't use the output column in the condition. I added the select wraper to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, just in case:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Table2
  WHERE @var = @defValue
    AND ... /* other conditions as necessary */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1
  FROM Table3
  WHERE @var <> @defValue
    AND ... /* other conditions as necessary */
);
```